# Android unbind Service on App crash or exit

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, android-service, android-service-binding

I am working on a Android app that binds to a Android service.

The problem is that that Android service is responsible of a Bluetooth connection with another device.

For now, my service exposes a `DisconnectBluetooth()` method, that will end the Bluetooth connection.

What I do is to call that `DisconnectBluetooth` method followed by a call to `unbindService`, within my `onDestroy` method, so when the app stops, the Bluetooth connection will be closed, and the service will be unbound.

The thing is that if my app **crashes**, or sometimes when I force it to **exit** by swipping it in the App Selector, the `onDestroy` method won't be called. The app will then be quitted, but the service is still alive, and so the Bluetooth connection is still alive too.

What can I do, to be sure to close the Bluetooth connection, and if possible unbind the service ?

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
      if (_api.isConnect()) { //<-- If bound to service, and everything OK
        _api.DisonnectBluetooth(); //<-- Close BT connection with device
        _api.ReleaseService(); //<-- Unbinds service
      }
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: **onDestroy()** is not synonymous with **unbindService()**.  Sounds like you might want a started service and bound service together.  Read this: developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html - `If you do allow your service to be started and bound, then when the service has been started, the system does not destroy the service when all clients unbind.   Instead, you must explicitly stop the service by calling stopSelf() or stopService().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always thought overriding `onUnbind()` method, would be called only if activity explicitly calls `unbindService()` method.

But no, even if my app crashes or force exit by swipping recent app selector, it is called. I so decided to use onunbind rather than onTaskRemoved

**NOTE :** I am using Xamarin, and I can't guarantee this to work on Java Android

Comment: Sorry about my earlier comment. The text of this answer doesn't read like an answer, but it does indeed answer the question.